# How to setup High available active-passive postgresql which has scheduled job running on server

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, high-availability

I am new to postgresql, I went through the Postgres documentation which provides details for the active passive server setup.
What I want is the scheduler in spring boot should run only on server which is pointing to active mode, and in passive mode the schedular should not run.
As soon as active goes down and passive takes over as new active, then jobs should start running on new server.
I just have 2 jobs , one runs each 5 mins and one runs everyday at 1AM.
Need help in achieving this

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe it’s English only, I think I need to rephrase the question in order to make it easy to understand what I am doing

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe updated, can you help in this?

Comment: Thanks, now I can read it. But this question is much too broad. You are asking for suggestions for an architecture, since this is a complicated requirement that requires additional software and complicated configuration. This cannot be answered in a Stackoverflow answer. You either have to start reading documentation, or you have to hire someone who knows this stuff.